# How to make strings literal when formatting?

Tags: formatting

When string formatting is supported, it's sometimes possible pass in a string which could contain a percentage symbol which would then be interpreted.

For example, this `frame-title-format` has a bug when the file name contains `%b`.

```lisp
(setq-default frame-title-format
  '((:eval
      (if (buffer-file-name)
        (abbreviate-file-name (buffer-file-name))
        "%b"))
     (:eval (if (buffer-modified-p) " *")) " emacs"))
```

How can a string have formatting characters converted into literals?

Comment: The `frame-title-format` has a long-standing bug that can lead to the name subsequently changing on its own ....  Setting the frame title by modifying the frame parameter directly is the best way to work around that bug.  The frame title parameter can also be set from the outset when creating the frame ...

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `format` and (for your example) <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `mode-line-format` both use the same escaping mechanism for the `%` metacharacters:

> The format control string may contain %-sequences meaning to substitute
>   the next available argument, or the argument explicitly specified:
>   ...
>   Use %% to put a single % into the output.

So to escape the meta-characters in a format STRING, you could do this:

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "%" "%%" STRING)
```

---

And for completeness: if you were calling `format` *yourself*, you would simply use:

```
(format "%s" STRING)
```

Comment: Maybe citing `C-h v mode-line-format` would fit the question's example better.

Comment: Very good point; I obviously wasn't paying enough attention.  Happily the `%%` escaping mechanism is the same in each case :)  Fixed now.